# Merge array key values

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have this array structure that contains ids of one tournament players:

```
array (
  0 => 
   array (
     0 => 
       array (
        'player' => 7,
        'gol' => 1,
       ),
     1 => 
       array (
        'player' => 9,
        'gol' => 1,
    ),
 ),
 1 => 
   array (
    0 => 
      array (
        'player' => 10,
        'gol' => 1,
      ),
    1 => 
      array (
        'player' => 9,
        'gol' => 1,
     ),
  ),
),
```

This array have some duplicates ('player'). I would to generate an array that not contains duplicate of players, and the result will be sum of each goal by player, such as:

```
 array(
     0 => 
       array (
        'player' => 7,
        'gol' => 1,
       ),
     1 => 
       array (
        'player' => 9,
        'gol' => 2,
      ),
     2 => 
       array (
        'player' => 10,
        'gol' => 1,
      ),
 ),
```

This is my code:

```
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    $players = [];
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();

        if (have_rows('field_name', $id)):
           while (have_rows('field_name', $id)) : the_row();
           $tmp = [];
           $player = get_sub_field('player_name', $id);
           $tmp['player'] = $player['ID'];
           $tmp['gol'] = get_sub_field('player_goal', $id);
           array_push($players, $tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use SUM and GROUP BY operators in your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$games = array (
    array(array("player"=>7,"gol"=>1),array("player"=>9,"gol"=>1)),
    array(array("player"=>10,"gol"=>1),array("player"=>9,"gol"=>1)),
); //Input array

$player = array();
foreach($games as $game) foreach($game as $gol) //For game and gol
@$player[$gol["player"]]+=$gol["gol"]; //sum gols

arsort($player); //sort by value

print_r($player);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [9] => 2
    [10] => 1
    [7] => 1
)
```

Comment: doesn't work using arsort. Structure is that:

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'player' => 11,
    'gol' => 2,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'player' => 10,
    'gol' => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'player' => 6,
    'gol' => '4',
  ),
)

Comment: @mariobros then a usort function is needed like `usort($player, function($a,$b) { return $b['gol']<=>$a['gol'];}` Edit : the `<=>` operator will work on 7.0+ version of PHP so just try to follow the manual if you are still in 5.6.* http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: could you edit your answer using array order by value?

Answer (score 1):

Naive way (I took the sample from FAEWZX answer ):

```
$games = array (
    array(array("player"=>7,"gol"=>1),array("player"=>9,"gol"=>1)),
    array(array("player"=>10,"gol"=>1),array("player"=>9,"gol"=>1)),
);

$player = array();
foreach($games as $game) 
{
    foreach($game as $gol)
    {
        if(in_array($gol['player'], array_column($player, 'player')))
        {
            foreach($player as $key => $value)
            {
                if($value['player'] == $gol['player'])
                {
                    $player[$key]['gol'] += $gol['gol'];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $player[] = $gol;
        }

    }
}
print_r($player);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [player] => 7
            [gol] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [player] => 9
            [gol] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [player] => 10
            [gol] => 1
        )
)
```